# How to print only once in loop?

Tags: python, loops

```
b = input().split(' ')
c = list(map(int,b))
y = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
    if c[i] %2 == 0:
        print(c[i])
        y = 1
    elif i == len(c) - 1 & y == 0:
        print('No number that is divisible by 2')
```

Code takes a list of numbers as input, then it prints all values divisible by 2, but if there are no such values it should print about this only once. My code works properly only in certain cases. I know another implementation but i need solution within 1 loop

Comment: If you only want to print once, don't do it in the loop. Put it after the loop.

Comment: You could use the mod% function

Answer (score 2):

Add break:

```py
b = input().split(' ')
c = list(map(int,b))
y = 0
for i in range(len(b)):
    if c[i] %2 == 0:
        print(c[i])
        y = 1
    elif i == len(c) - 1 & y == 0:
        print('No number that is divisible by 2')
        break
```

Comment: thx, but problem was that i used '&' instead of 'and'

Answer (score 0):

You may want to simplify by calculating the numbers divisible by 2 first, then deciding what to print:

```py
nums = map(int, input().split(' '))
div2 = [i for i in nums if not i % 2]
if div2:
    for i in div2:
        print(i)
else:
    print('No number that is divisible by 2')
```